# If two naturals $m, n$ are not divisible by $5$, then $m^4 - n^4$ is.

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

**Problem**

A math book wants me to prove that given two natural numbers $m, \ n$ are not divisible by $5$, then the difference $m^4 - n^4$ *is* divisible by $5$.

**Thoughts**

The only method I can think of now, is to go through all the possible ways of writing a numbers not divisible by 5, and find the difference of all the permutations' powers.

I.e. $(5k + 1)^4 - (5k + 1)^4$, $(5k+2)^4 - (5k+1)^4$ etc, and check that each of these are divisble by 5.

While I believe this will eventually work, I also believe that there has to be a better way.

Any tips here would be appreciated!

Comment: Another way: $\,mn(m^4\!-n^4) = (\color{#c00}{m^5\!-m})n + m(\color{#c00}{n-n^5})$ and $5$ divides $\rm\color{#c00}{red}$ terms by Fermat, so $\ldots$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an appplication of [Fermat’s little theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatsLittleTheorem.html): since $5$ is a prime, $m^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem

Comment: Oh neat! I was thinking Fermat at some point, but I forgot that little corollary for $a^{p-1}$.

Comment: So $m^4 - n^4 = 1-1 = 0 \pmod 5$?

Comment: @Alec Yes, that is the solution. Note that you need the condition that $m,n$ are not divisible by $5$ for the application of the corollary.

Answer (score 4):

$$m^4-n^4=(m-n)(m+n)(m^2+n^2)$$

Now modulo $5$ we have $m^2+n^2\equiv m^2+n^2-5n^2=(m+2n)(m-2n)$.

If $n$ is not divisible by $5$, the numbers $\pm n, \pm 2n$ cover all the non-zero residues modulo $5$, and one of the factors $m\mp n, m\mp 2n$ is therefore divisible by $5$.

Comment: Good stuff. I wouldn't have been able to conclude that myself, but I wrote a separate answer which starts similarly to yours, but branches off a bit.

Comment: @Alec Yes - yours is nice way of seeing it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to include an alternative solution here, in addition to the already good answers. This one is inspired by @MarkBennet's answer.

$$\begin{align*} m^4-n^4&=(m^2-n^2)(m^2+n^2)\\ &=(m-n)(m+n)(m^2+n^2)\\ &\equiv (m-n)(m+n)(m^2-4n^2)\\ &= (m-n)(m+n)(m-2n)(m+2n)\\ &\equiv (m-n)(m-2n)(m-3n)(m-4n) \pmod{5}, \end{align*}$$

Since neither $m$ nor $n$ is divisible by 5, one (and only one) of these factors must be.